# Como puedo optimizar esta consulta?

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_pvPrueba]
as
CREATE TABLE #PV
(
consecuttransform int,
consecutivo int,
fecha date,
nommov nvarchar(80),
codart nvarchar(30),
cantidad int,
NombreEntrada nvarchar(50),
CODUNIDAD nvarchar(30),
codbodega nvarchar(30),
valor int,
COSTO int,
enommov nvarchar(50),
ereferencia int,
eCodArt nvarchar(30),
Nombre nvarchar(50),
MES INT,
AÑO INT,
codigo nvarchar(30),
codinsumo nvarchar(30),
cantidad2 int

)

insert into #PV
SELECT T0.consecuttransform,T0.consecutivo,T0.fecha,T0.nommov, T0.codart , T0.cantidad ,T2.Nombre as NombreEntrada , T2.CODUNIDAD , T0.codbodega ,T0.valor , T2.COSTO, T0.enommov , T0.ereferencia  ,
       T0.ECodArt,T3.Nombre, DATEPART(MONTH, T0.fecha) AS 'MES' , DATEPART(YEAR, T0.fecha) AS 'AÑO' ,
       CASE WHEN T1.codigo IS NULL THEN 'No ingr.' ELSE T1.codigo END AS codigo, 
       CASE WHEN T1.codinsumo IS NULL THEN 'No ingr.' ELSE T1.codinsumo END AS codinsumo,        
       CASE WHEN T1.cantidad IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE T1.cantidad END AS cantidad
FROM [APTDPORCIPOS].DBO.Vsta_transformaciones T0 INNER JOIN Vsta_enctransformaciones enc on enc.consecutivo=T0.consecutivo COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
                              LEFT JOIN [APTDPORCIPOS].DBO.tblmvtofichatecnica T1 ON T0.CodArt=T1.Codigo AND T0.ECodArt=T1.codinsumo COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
                              INNER JOIN [APTDPORCIPOS].DBO.tblarticulos T2 ON T0.codart=T2.Codigo COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
                              INNER JOIN [APTDPORCIPOS].DBO.tblarticulos T3 ON T0.ecodart=T3.Codigo COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS                             
WHERE  T0.consecutivo=enc.consecutivo COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS AND YEAR(T0.fecha) = '2019'-- and enc.consecutivo=19

UNION

SELECT enc.consecuttransform, enc.consecutivo, enc.fecha, enc.nommov, enc.codart , T0.cantidad,
(SELECT A0.Nombre FROM [APTDPORCIPOS].DBO.tblarticulos A0 WHERE  A0.codigo = enc.codart) AS NombreENtrada,
(SELECT A0.CODUNIDAD FROM [APTDPORCIPOS].DBO.tblarticulos A0 WHERE A0.codigo =  enc.codart) AS CODUNIDAD,
enc.codbodega, enc.valor,
(SELECT T2.COSTO FROM [APTDPORCIPOS].DBO.tblarticulos T2 WHERE T2.codigo = enc.codart) AS COSTO, enc.enommov , enc.ereferencia , T0.EcodArt ,
(SELECT A0.Nombre FROM [APTDPORCIPOS].DBO.tblarticulos A0 WHERE A0.codigo = ficha.codinsumo) AS Nombre, 
DATEPART(MONTH, enc.fecha) AS 'MES' , DATEPART(YEAR, enc.fecha) AS 'AÑO', ficha.codigo, ficha.codinsumo, ficha.cantidad 
FROM [APTDPORCIPOS].DBO.Vsta_enctransformaciones enc, [APTDPORCIPOS].DBO.Vsta_transformaciones T0, [APTDPORCIPOS].DBO.tblmvtofichatecnica ficha
WHERE ficha.codigo = T0.codart AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT CODART FROM [APTDPORCIPOS].DBO.Vsta_transformaciones T0 
WHERE CODIGO = T0.CODART AND CODINSUMO = T0.ECODART AND t0.consecutivo=enc.consecutivo) AND
enc.consecutivo = T0.consecutivo AND YEAR(T0.fecha) = '2019'

GROUP BY enc.consecuttransform,enc.consecutivo,enc.fecha,enc.movmiento,enc.nommov,enc.referencia,enc.codart, T0.cantidad , T0.ECodArt ,enc.codbodega,enc.cantidad,
         enc.valor,enc.econsecutivo,enc.efecha,enc.emovimiento,enc.enommov,enc.ereferencia,ficha.codinsumo,enc.ecodbodega,ficha.codigo,
         ficha.codinsumo,ficha.cantidad
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Cual seria el problema que tenes?

Comment: Tu consulta tiene muchos problemas. Pero creo que la ayuda que necesitas va mucho más allá del alcance de este sitio, tomando en cuenta tu pregunta acerca del error de la vista. Para optimizar correctamente una consulta, Necesitas compartir definiciones de tablas incluyendo índices y de preferencia un plan de ejecución.